# JavaScript .split function does not work in all browsers

Tags: javascript

This function works in some IE browsers, but does not work in all. 
IE 8 gives me an error:

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.3; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 15:18:21 UTC

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 9
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: file:///G:/1.html
```

Code:

```
GetLink();

function GetLink() {
   selectedOption = "asdasdasd: asdasdas|asdadasd:asdadsasd|asdasdasd:asdasdad";
   ROOM = selectedOption.split("|")[0].trim().split(":")[1].trim();
   BUILDING = selectedOption.split("|")[1].trim().split(":")[1].trim();
   var ret = "room_chart.jsp?room=" + ROOM + "&building=" + BUILDING;
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `split` method is fine, it's `trim` that's causing the problem. You can use this little [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

`String.prototype.trim` is not available in IE < 9. The snippet of code above simply adds the `split` method to `String.prototype` if it doesn't already exist, and behaves exactly as you would expect the native implementation to.

If you are using jQuery, there is a [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method you can use.

Comment: You can also try some of these trim methods, which are potentially faster: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript